# I can't solve this error in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

I don't know what this error means:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Untitled.main(Untitled.java:16)

```
class Untitled {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     int x=3;
     int y=5;
     double d=0;
     int[][] route = new int[][]{
      { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 },
      { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 },
      { 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 },
      { 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40 },
      { 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50 }
    };
     int[][] distance = new int[10][];
     for (int i=0;i<route.length;i++) {
        for (int j=0;j<route[0].length;j++) {
            distance[i][j]=route[i][j]-x;
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't know, so the first thing to do is go bother the online expert community with it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a 2Dimensional array wrong defined.

change

```
int[][] distance = new int[10][];
```

with

```
int[][] distance = new int[5][10];
```

Comment: I did that but it didn't work.

Comment: what error it returns?

Comment: I was wrong on 2D array initialize, I have edit my answer, retry, and if still won't work, write the exceptions